# Telegram web app does not display the stream from the webcam on iOS (everything works in the browser)

Tags: reactjs, telegram, telegram-bot, webcam

There was such a problem, I wrote in react to an application with a cap on the head (face-api.js) in real time (via Webcam), on IOS on the website in the browser the webcam displays the image on the screen, while in the telegram web app it does not displays, although you give permission to use the camera, I don’t know what the problem is, it works fine on Android and PC everywhere. In Eruda on iOS in Telegram there are no errors in the console, the video tag is in the markup. I will be glad to any suggestions that can somehow potentially cure this, here is the link to the app: https://t.me/test4525623_bot/mtsMask link to the browser version: https://danchikslaziet.github.io/testTG

App.js code (there are essentially no other components):

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import {detectAllFaces} from 'face-api.js';
import Webcam from "react-webcam";
import * as faceapi from 'face-api.js';
import imgPath from './images/overlay-cap.png';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const webcamRef = useRef(null);
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const hatImageRef = useRef(null);


  useEffect(() => {
    function parseQuery(queryString) {
      let query = {};
      let pairs = (queryString[0] === '?' ? queryString.substr(1) : queryString).split('&');
      for (let i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
          let pair = pairs[i].split('=');
          query[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1] || '');
      }
      return query;
    }

    let app = window.Telegram.WebApp;
    let query = app.initData;
    let user_data_str = parseQuery(query).user;
    // let user_data = JSON.parse(user_data_str)
    app.expand();
    app.ready();
    console.log(user_data_str);

    const startFaceDetection = async () => {
      const MODEL_URL = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/models';
      await faceapi.loadTinyFaceDetectorModel(MODEL_URL);
      await faceapi.loadFaceLandmarkModel(MODEL_URL);
      await faceapi.loadFaceRecognitionModel(MODEL_URL);
      await faceapi.loadSsdMobilenetv1Model(MODEL_URL);
      
      const videoEl = webcamRef.current.video;
      const canvas = canvasRef.current;

      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      setInterval(async () => {
        const detections = await detectAllFaces(videoEl).withFaceLandmarks();
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        detections.forEach((detection) => {
          const hatImage = hatImageRef.current;
          hatImage.style.display = 'none';
          hatImage.style.position = 'absolute';

          const landmarks = detection.landmarks;
          const leftEyeBrow = landmarks.getLeftEyeBrow();
          const rightEyeBrow = landmarks.getRightEyeBrow();

          const leftPoint = leftEyeBrow[0];
          const rightPoint = rightEyeBrow.splice(-1)[0];
          const width = (rightPoint.x - leftPoint.x)*2;

          canvas.width = width;
          canvas.height = 91;
          canvas.style.width = width + 'px';
          canvas.style.left =  (leftPoint.x - width * 0.10) - 10 + 'px';
          canvas.style.top = (leftEyeBrow[0].y - width * 0.55) + 'px';

          context.drawImage(hatImage, 0, 0, canvas.width, 91);
        });
      }, 300);
    };
    startFaceDetection();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Webcam
        className='App__video'
        ref={webcamRef}
        mirrored={false}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
          zIndex: 1,
        }}
      />
      <canvas
        ref={canvasRef}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          zIndex: 100,
          aspectRatio: '171 / 91'
        }}
        />
      <img
        ref={hatImageRef}
        src={imgPath} // Путь к изображению кепки
        className='cap'
        alt="Hat"
        style={{
          zIndex: 100,
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I thought there might be a problem with the Webcam component, but that’s not the problem. As far as I know, Telegram uses WKWebView to display the application, I assume that this may be the problem. When I give permission to use the camera in Telegram, the green indicator lights up, that is, access to the camera is actually enabled, but there is no display from the camera.